# Problema footer bootstrap 5.0.2

Tags: css, bootstrap, spring-boot, thymeleaf

Estoy haciendo un sitio de noticias con `springboot`, `thymeleaf`, y `bootstrap 5.0.2`

El problema es que el `footer` se sobrepone a las noticias, esta es la imagen sin hacer scroll:

[image: Imagen sin scroll]

Esta es la imagen scrolleando el máximo que me permite:

[image: Imagen con scroll]

No encuentro la manera de hacer que el `footer` se vaya mas para abajo y deje espacio a la noticia completa. He probado con `fixed-bottom`, `v100`, `vh-100`.

Adjunto el código:

```
<footer th:fragment="footer"class="bg-dark fixed-bottom">
    <div class="text-center p-3 container-fluid">
       <p class="text-white">Copyright &copy<span id="fecha"></span>
       <a class="text-decoration-none text-warning fw-bold" rel="nofollow noopener noreferrer" href="https://github.com/Agslz" target="_blank">
        Agustin Schulze</a> | Todos los derechos reservados.</p>
    </div>
</footer>
```

Además, adjunto el código del index:

```
<div class="container-fluid vh-100">
    <div class="pt-4 container">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-12 col-md-4 mb-4" th:each="noticia : ${noticias}">
                    <div class="card bg-dark">
                     <img style="height:200px;width:353px" th:src="@{'data:image/jpeg;base64,'+${noticia.imagen}}"
                            class="card-img-top rounded-3 imagenstyle" alt="Imagen HTML">
                        <div class="card-body"> 
                            <h3 class="card-title text-white text-capitalize fs-2"
                                th:text="${noticia.titulo}"></h3>
                            <!--    <p class="card-text text-white m-0">
                                Autor : <small class="text-muted fst-italic  text-capitalize"
                                    th:text="${noticia.autor}"></small>
                            </p>-->
                            <p class="card-text text-white">
                                Publicada el : <small class="text-muted fst-italic"
                                    th:text="${noticia.alta}"></small>
                            </p>
                            <!-- <div class="text-end">
                                <a sec:authorize="isAuthenticated()"
                                    class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-warning text-decoration-none  fw-bolder"
                                    th:href="@{/admin/completa/} + ${noticia.id}">Leer Más </a> <a
                                    sec:authorize="!isAuthenticated()"
                                    class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-warning text-decoration-none  fw-bolder"
                                    th:href="@{/home/lectura/} + ${noticia.id}">Leer Más </a>
                            </div> -->
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<footer th:replace="layout/plantilla :: footer"></footer>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No es un problema en el `footer` sino, mas bien en el `container`.

Para solucionarlo basta con agregarle suficiente `margin-bottom` para que el contenido sea visible al hacer scroll. Por ejemplo:

```
<div class="pt-4 mb-5 container">
```

También puedes aprovechar el `padding-bottom` para agregarle aún mas espacio. Por ejemplo:

```
<div class="py-5 mb-5 container">
```

La clase `py-5` agrega el `padding` tanto arriba como abajo, es equivalente a tener `pt-5` y `pb-5`.

Otra opción es reducir el `padding` del `footer` a 2, por ejemplo.

Si las clases de `bootstrap` no te dan el espacio suficiente, puedes agregarle un `margin-bottom` personalizado con tus propios estilos `css`.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Bootstrap demo</title>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-Zenh87qX5JnK2Jl0vWa8Ck2rdkQ2Bzep5IDxbcnCeuOxjzrPF/et3URy9Bv1WTRi" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container-fluid vh-100">
    <div class="py-5 mb-5 container">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-12 col-md-4 mb-4" th:each="noticia : ${noticias}">
            <div class="card bg-dark">
              <img style="height:200px;width:353px" th:src="@{'data:image/jpeg;base64,'+${noticia.imagen}}" class="card-img-top rounded-3 imagenstyle" alt="Imagen HTML">
              <div class="card-body">
                <h3 class="card-title text-white text-capitalize fs-2" th:text="${noticia.titulo}"></h3>
                <!--    <p class="card-text text-white m-0">
                                Autor : <small class="text-muted fst-italic  text-capitalize"
                                    th:text="${noticia.autor}"></small>
                            </p>-->
                <p class="card-text text-white">
                  Publicada el : <small class="text-muted fst-italic" th:text="${noticia.alta}"></small>
                </p>
                <!-- <div class="text-end">
                                <a sec:authorize="isAuthenticated()"
                                    class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-warning text-decoration-none  fw-bolder"
                                    th:href="@{/admin/completa/} + ${noticia.id}">Leer Más </a> <a
                                    sec:authorize="!isAuthenticated()"
                                    class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-warning text-decoration-none  fw-bolder"
                                    th:href="@{/home/lectura/} + ${noticia.id}">Leer Más </a>
                            </div> -->
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <footer th:fragment="footer" class="bg-dark fixed-bottom">
    <div class="text-center p-2 container-fluid">
      <p class="text-white">Copyright &copy<span id="fecha"></span>
        <a class="text-decoration-none text-warning fw-bold" rel="nofollow noopener noreferrer" href="https://github.com/Agslz" target="_blank">
        Agustin Schulze</a> | Todos los derechos reservados.</p>
    </div>
  </footer>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-OERcA2EqjJCMA+/3y+gxIOqMEjwtxJY7qPCqsdltbNJuaOe923+mo//f6V8Qbsw3" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias!!!